# Multithreaded proxy application is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy application, but I'm facing problems in server socket. The Server Socket is not accepting the connection and returning a socket. Hence, I cannot test the proxy application. What is wrong?

The problem line is indicated in WebServe.java:

```
public class WebServe implements Runnable {
    Socket soc;
    OutputStream os;
    BufferedReader is;
    String resource;

    WebServe(Socket s) throws IOException {
        soc = s;
        os = soc.getOutputStream();
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void run() {
        System.err.println("Running");
        getRequest();
        returnResponse();
        close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Proxy Thread");
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8080);
            for (;;) {
                s.setSoTimeout(10000);
                WebServe w = new WebServe(s.accept()); // Problem is here
                Thread thr = new Thread(w);
                thr.start();
                w.getRequest();
                w.returnResponse();
                w.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Server");
        }
    }

    void getRequest() {
        System.out.println("Getting Request");
        try {
            String message;
            while ((message = is.readLine()) != null) {
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    break;
                }
                System.err.println(message);
                StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(message);
                String token = t.nextToken();
                if (token.equals("GET")) {
                    resource = t.nextToken();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error receiving Web request");
        }
    }

    void returnResponse() {
        int c;
        try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("." + resource);
            while ((c = f.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(c);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException is reading in web");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            is.close();
            os.close();
            soc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in closing connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    try {
        System.out.println("Proxy Thread");
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket (8080);
        for (;;){
            s.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

Move that ahead of the loop. You don't need to keep setting it. You don't really need it at all actually.

```
            WebServe w  = new WebServe (s.accept()); //Problem is here
```

The problem is here only because you set a socket timeout you don't actually need.

```
            Thread thr = new Thread (w);
            thr.start();
```

So far so good.

```
            w.getRequest();
            w.returnResponse();
            w.close();
```

Remove. The next problem is here. The `run()` method of `WebServ` already does this.

As to the rest, you aren't writing an HTTP header in the response.